# Sum of product of Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis

I want to compute the following product

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^{N}\left(\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{s}\exp(2\pi is\frac{t}{N}\right)\left(\sum_{z=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{z}\exp(-2\pi iz\frac{t}{N})\right)$$
If $N\rightarrow\infty$ we can approximate it with integral:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{s}\exp(2\pi isx\right)\left(\sum_{z=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{z}\exp(2\pi izx)\right)dx=\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{s}\sum_{z=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{z}\int_{0}^{1}\exp(2\pi i(s-z))dx$$
Hence $s=z$ and we have 
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{s}^{2}$$

On the other hand this product  is equal to:
$$\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{s}\right)\left(\sum_{z=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{z}\right)\left(\sum_{t=1}^{N}\exp(2\pi i(s-z)\frac{t}{N})\right)=\sum_{w=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{s}a_{s+Nw}$$

We have
$$\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{s}^{2}+\sum_{w=-\infty,w\neq0}^{\infty}\sum_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{s}a_{s+Nw}$$

Now I don't see why the second term will disappear.

Which is correct?

Comment: There is an error somewhere in your penultimate formula. Could you please re-edit? Also, is this an isolated calculation or exercise? if not, could you give us a bit more background context (for instance, why you're interested)?

Comment: You are taking limits as $N\to\infty$. In the sum
$\sum_{w\ne0}a_{s+Nw}$ the terms thin out as $N$ increases.
Assuming $a_n\to0$ quickly enough as $n\to\pm\infty$ then
$\sum_{w\ne0}a_{s+Nw}$ will tend to $0$.

Comment: Following Robin's comment, you need some hypotheses on the decay of your coefficients in order for the Fourier series to converge.

Comment: Yemon Choi, thanks, I have re-edited. I have obtained this expression, while solving some least square problem. And I use Fourier series of basis functions.  



 

Comment: Robin Chapman, Scott Carnahan

In my case Fourier coefficients $a_s=sinc(s)^p$   function. But still,  I am confused about the limits.  Because $s->\infty$, 
hence $s+Nw$ can be small, depending in which order I'll take limits.


Comment: Actualy not, Fourier coefficients in my case $a_s=sinc(s/K)^p$.
K<N, but the rate of  K is unknown

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the Dominated Convergence Theorem, see [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155801/convergence-of-a-trigonometric-series/156001#156001).

In details:
$$
\sum_{w\neq0}\sum_{s} a_s a_{s+Nw}
$$
is better written 
$$
\sum_{s}\sum_{z} b_{s,z}^N
$$
where
$$
b_{s,z}^N = a_{s}a_{z} \mbox{ when } z=s \mbox{ mod } N,\, N\neq0 \mbox{ and } b_{s,z}^N=0 \mbox{ otherwise.} 
$$
Now, $|b_{s,z}^N|\leq |a_{s}||a_{z}|$ for all $N$, and $$\sum\sum|a_{s}||a_{z}|=(\sum |a_{s}|)^2<\infty.$$
On the other hand, for any fixed $z, s$
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty} b_{s,z}^N = 0 \,(\mbox{ since } a_{s+Nw} \to 0 \mbox{ with }N)
$$
Now apply the DCT to conclude.