# Convergence of a Trigonometric Series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, limits-and-convergence, trigonometric-sums

After working with a Fourier series for a while, I realized that it would be of great help to me if I could prove that the following limit is zero:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m\cos(m(N+1))\sin(mN)}{(4m^2-1)\sin(m)}$$

I tried to do several things and I can show that with a trivial upper bound that if $\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{m^2|\sin(m)|}$ converges then the limit will clearly be zero, but this only seems to complicate things, as I think I would have to introduce notions of Diophantine approximation to show that the denominator doesn't get too crazy.

Comment: The numerator is missing a ")".  If it's supposed to be
$\cos(m(N+1)) \sin(mN)$ then it converges because
$|\sin(mN) / \sin(m)| \leq N \ll_N 1$ and the other factors are $O(1/m^2)$.

Comment: Cross post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652609/convergence-of-trigonometric-dirichlet-series

Comment: @rghthndsd Those two questions don't look the same to me.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Let $N$ get arbitrarily large and it is no longer bounded.

Comment: Is your question whether the sum converges (in which case Noam's answer is right), or whether it converges to a value bounded independently of $N$?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Bounded independently of $N$, sorry if I wasn't clear. Please feel free to change it if you want to make it more easily understandable.

Comment: @Ethan,I think you should change it, stating what it is that you want; as it stands, Noam Elkies has answered the question.

Comment: Note also the minor simplification: by the formula for $\cos\alpha \sin\beta$,
an equivalent question is the behavior of the same sum with the numerator 
replaced by the simpler $(-1)^m \sin(N'm)$ [with $N'=2N+1$].

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out earlier, 
$$a_{N,m}:=\frac{(-1)^m\cos(m(N+1))\sin(mN)}{N(4m^2-1)\sin(m)}$$
satisfies
$$
\left|a_{N,m}\right|\leq \frac{1}{(4m^2-1)},
\mbox{
and }\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(4m^2-1)} < \infty.$$
On the other hand, for every $m$, there holds
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} a_{N,m} = 0.$$ 
Thus the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) does it for you,
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{m} a_{N,m} =0.
$$  (If you have never seen this Theorem, it says, for series:
 Given ${a_{N,m}}$,, if

- $|a_{N,m}| < b_m$ for all $N$ and  $\sum_{m} b_m$ converges
- for $m$ fixed, $a_{N,m}\to c_m$

then

- $\sum_{m} |a_{N,m} -c_m| \to 0$
- $\sum_m c_m$ converges

  and consequently
  $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_m a_{N,m} = \sum_m c_m
  $).